# After installing dnsmasq resolv.conf changes to 127.0.0.1

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dns

In `Ubuntu 16.04`, after installing `dnsmasq` service it changes `/etc/resolv.conf` nameserver to `127.0.0.1`.

Where does this IP come from? Where to change it? I know that this file is linked to another and that I can add secondary nameserver as well, but I want to have only one and It would be lovely to change the one (`127.0.0.1`) that is generated by `dnsmasq` to example `8.8.8.8`.

Is it possible to do so without deleting the symlink and creating a new `resolv.conf` file?

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 is the localhost on the loopback network.  Dnsmasq assumes, that, if you want to install a DNS server, you want to use it. So, it will point the resolv.conf to the DNS server that has just been installed. It does so via the looopback network

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 is the loopback IP address, meaning it always represents the local machine. So by changing your machine's `/etc/resolv.conf` to only have that address, it tells processes on that machine to use the local instance of `dnsmasq` as the DNS server. When set up this way, `dnsmasq` will have a separate configuration file that tells it where its real upstream DNS servers are.